# Octonions in Mathematica

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

Is there a package or Notebook for *Mathematica* that can enable me to do some numerical calculations with [octonions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonions)? Maybe a way to plug-in the octonion multiplication table?

Comment: A Google search for "octonions mathematica" turns up http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5194/ as well as several demonstrations and multiplication tables.

Comment: If you try the link above, and it works for you, perhaps you can post an answer yourself with short review of the package.

Answer (score 15):

Yesterday I posted THE comprehensive list of 480 octonions, Fano planes and multiplication tables [here](http://theoryofeverything.org/MyToE/?p=1026). You may be interested in the some of the code base for that, which you can find in [this notebook](http://theoryofeverything.org/TOE/JGM/Octonions.nb).

It includes a Cayley-Dickson doubling of the built-in *Mathematica* quaternions to perform general octonion math. An interactive [CDF is also available](http://theoryofeverything.org/TOE/JGM/Octonions.cdf) (but I suspect the users of this forum don't need that ;-)

[image]

This is the foundation for some of the visualizations used in an interactive visualization of Octonions, E8 Lie groups and particle physics [here](http://theoryofeverything.org/MyToE/?page_id=755). While I have several related Wolfram Demonstrations on [Dynkin Diagrams](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DynkinDiagrams/) and [E8 Particles](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ParticleGeneratorBasedOnTheE8LieAlgebra/), I have been unable to successfully publish that first Octonion visualization pane.